# Count the amount of occurrences of a character in a string: how can I interpret this code?

Tags: c, loops

The assignment asks to print out the number of times a chosen character appears in an input (no length limit) string. I wanted to solve it by only using do or do-while loops, and after a bit of googling I found this code (source: https://www.tutorialgateway.org/c-program-to-count-all-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string/.).
I get the gist of it, but there are many things I still haven't covered, such as the meaning of str[i], the meaning of the variable `ch`, and kind of how the structure works. How can I interpret it piece by piece? Or if there's any simpler way, how can I work on it? I'm a beginner and I fear this is much easier than expected but I don't have the base to move on, thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main() {
    char str[10], ch;
    int i, Count;
    i = Count = 0;
 
    printf("\n Please Enter any String :  ");
    gets(str);
    
    printf("\n Please Enter the Character that you want to Search for :  ");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (str[i] == ch) {
            Count++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n The Total Number of times '%c' has Occurred = %d ", ch, Count);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For reasons you'll learn later, this is a terrible example program. For your own future benefit, never use `gets()`. It's a dangerous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i am giving an easy example regarding that problem with a proper explanation. Hope you might understand.

- char is a datatype which will accepts character type of variable. Here str[100] will be an array of length 100, where we will store our search example. ch is a character type variable where we will store the character for which we will find the concurrence.
- i and count are integer variables where i will be loop variable and the count will keep count of the concurrence.
- after taking the text string using puts function we are storing it in the str[100] array.
- then we are taking the search letter and stored it in ch.
- we are now running for loop from 0 to the length of the string we have given.
  strlen() function returning us the length.
- now str[i] will search from i=0 to the length size of the string. each time loop will go forward one by one letter and compare the letter with the letter inside ch.
- if match found then we will increase the count value.

after the ending of the loop count will be the result of the concurrency.

reference: [Concurrency of a letter in a string](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/c-program-to-count-all-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100], ch;
    int i, Count;
    Count = 0;

    printf("\n Please Enter any String :  ");
    gets(str);

    printf("\n Please Enter the Character that you want to Search for :  ");
    scanf("%c", &ch);

    for(i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == ch)  
        {
            Count++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n The Total Number of times '%c' has Occured = %d ", ch, Count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Best to avoid answers with the obsolete [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359), even if OP uses it.

Comment: Rather than potentially recalculate the string length, simply test for the _null character_.  Also, this answer's `for(i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)` iterates 1 more than  OP's better  `while (str[i] != '\0') {`

Comment: `i <= strlen(str)` is not recommended. `'\0'` should not be considered part of the string. The classic termination test is `str[i] != '\0'`. Furthermore,`gets()` should not be used for this or any coding problem.

Comment: thank you, this clarified some things

Comment: Well this was very much shortcut way to solve it. But for problem solving purpose its not recommended to use gets() or strlen() as @chux - Reinstate Monica
and chqrlie said. you can create your own custom code to find length without strlrn() and store string without gets(). I am giving you two references where you will get idea to do that.

Comment: Now take a challenge, replace those using the way discussed in these references. [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-string-input-space-c-3-different-methods/), [link](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/string-length#:~:text=Calculate%20Length%20of%20String%20without%20Using%20strlen()%20Function&text=Here%2C%20using%20a%20for%20loop,stored%20in%20the%20i%20variable.)

Answer (score 0):

The code has the following parts:

1)The header files: These contain predefined functions like `scanf()` which you use in your program

2)The main function: Here you are performing your character count. Usually, this function contains the driver code for the program

`ch` is a variable for the character you want to count in your string. You are taking this as input from the user using `scanf()`

`str` is the string you are performing your count operation in. It is also taken as input.

`str[i]` is used to denote the index `i` in the string. For example in "test", the index of 's' will be 2 as it is the 3rd character and your index starts from 0.

Final note: I recommend going through the basic syntax and usage of arrays if you do not know indexing. Also, as someone commented, do not use `gets()`. It causes security issues in programs as user can access stack values by giving malicious inputs containing format specifiers.
Instead, use a `scanf` with proper format specifiers or use `fgets()` when accessing content from files.

Comment: thank you, you cleared out the variables side. I also thought that gets() was a special command and not a bad version of scanf, thank you for explaining that too, it wasn't obvious